# Player not moving in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    // This is a reference to the Rigidbody component called "rb"
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 4000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 100f;

    // We marked this as "Fixed"Update because we
    // are using it to mess with physics.   
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Add a forward force
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); 

        if( Input.GetKey("d") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if( Input.GetKey("a") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

[Unity - Player not moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gq7E.png)

Please help.

Comment: Attach a screen shot with your player object selected, our rigidBody component visible in Inspector and your player being focus in Scene and Game view.

Comment: Make sure the game view is focused when you try. Otherwise, the inputs won't be captured.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a few things. First, trying taking out Time.deltaTime in FixedUpdate. When it comes adding forces in FixedUpdate, you normally don't need to useTime.deltaTime.

Secondly, try creating a physics material with zero friction and attaching that to the player object's box collider.

Comment: "For reading the delta time it is recommended to use Time.deltaTime instead because it automatically returns the right delta time if you are inside a FixedUpdate function or Update function." https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html

Comment: Using Transform.Translate requires you to use Time.delta time: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

However, adding forces does not require it, as the example code lacks it:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

This is because how physics are calculated within Unity. User angularsen has experimented with it here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/771979/why-using-deltatime-with-addforce.html?childToView=1488426#answer-1488426

TL/DR: You don't need to multiply time.deltaTime for addforces.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to move your logic to get inputs into the `Update()` method. From there, you can set a value for the force then add this force to the RigidBody in `FixedUpdate()`. This way, we will be sure the logic for getting input is detected every frame.

```
private float movement = 0f;

void Update()
{
    if( Input.GetKey("d") )
    {
        movement = sidewaysForce;
    }
    else if ( Input.GetKey("a") )
    {
        movement = -sidewaysForce;
    }
    else
    {
        movement = 0f;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime); 

    rb.AddForce(movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

I've also updated `Time.deltaTime` to `Time.fixedDeltaTime` since you are calling it in `FixedUpdate()`.

Finally, you may want to test with different force modes when adding the sideways force.